# Existe-t-il un nom pour quelqu'un qui rejette toujours la faute sur les autres ?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Comment nomme-t-on une personne qui considère que ses erreurs viennent toujours d'autrui ?

Par exemple :

> J'ai mal répondu parce que la question était mal posée.
>
> Je n'ai pas marqué ce but parce que la passe était mauvaise.

Dans les deux exemples que je donne, je suppose que la personne aurait réussi si elle avait été meilleure. Mais elle refuse de reconnaître qu'elle pourrait s'améliorer en blâmant une tierce personne. L'orgueilleux refuse de reconnaître ses faiblesses (n'est-il pas le meilleur ?), mais pas nécessairement en les reprochant à autrui.

Comment: In English, I'd call such a person an "arrogant, know-it-all jerk," also known as a "[Mickipedia](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Mickipedia). (The worst offenders will refer to themselves as "polymaths"). In addition to displaying the trait you describe, they also rarely apologize and are therefore known as "non-apologists." I'm not sure if any of these English terms translate into French (except maybe "M/Mme je-sais-tout"), but maybe they can help you find the right one in French.

Comment: Mais peut-être que la question (de l'exemple, pas la tienne) était *vraiment* mal posée... ;-)

Comment: Alors c'est celui qui a posé la question qui doit se remettre en question et pour qui le terme que je recherche devrait s'appliquer. ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

En général, on aura tendance à parler de *mauvaise foi* je pense. On dira alors que cette personne *fait preuve de mauvaise foi*.

Le principe de la mauvaise foi, c'est d'utiliser des arguments fallacieux, ou de jouer sur les faiblesses de l'argumentation adverse, pour retourner les torts sur l'autre plutôt que sur soi.

Plus simplement, ça peut se rapporter aussi à de la simple hypocrisie.

Comment: merci, c'est la notion que je recherchais. Mais avant d'approuver la réponse, j'aimerais savoir s'il n'existe pas un nom ou un adjectif pour désigner "quelqu'un qui fait preuve de mauvaise foi" (Je n'en ai pas trouvé, mais je voudrais être certain que ça n'existe pas)

Comment: Si tu considère que la mauvaise fois c'est de l'hypocrisie, tu peux alors tout simplement utiliser hypocrite.

Comment: l'hypocrisie va dans les deux sens, et consiste le plus souvent à dire ce que l'autre voudrait entendre (même si on pense le contraire). Dans le cas d'une personne qui est de mauvaise foi, ce n'est pas vraiment ce que les autres veulent entendre.

Comment: Ha, je suis pas tout à fait d'accord... pour moi, l'hypocrisie, c'est plus dire quelque chose que l'on n'applique pas à soit même. Autrement dit, reprocher qlq chose à qlq un alors que l'erreur vient de nous est de l'hypocrisie. Mais effectivement, contenter qlq'un par des compliments alors qu'on ne le pense pas est aussi de l'hypocrisie.  Mais si on n'utilise pas hypocrite, je ne vois pas quoi utiliser d'autre pour "faire preuve de mauvaise fois"... peut etre "expert en mauvaise fois" LOL

Comment: Attention quand même, la mauvaise foi est quelque chose de plus large que le fait de rejeter la faute sur les autres. Pareil pour l'hypocrisie, ce n'est qu'un concept voisin, attention aux confusions...

Comment: J'associe ce que tu décris plutôt à une "argumentation" [*ad hominem*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_hominem) qu'à de la mauvaise foi à proprement parler. [*Mauvaise foi*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mauvaise_foi) renvoie directement à *hypocrite*, d'ailleurs. Dans tous les cas, c'est supposer que la personne qui fait ça en a vaguement conscience et est déloyale, plutôt que simplement trop sûre d'elle. Est-ce que c'est vraiment le cas ?

Answer (score 5):

On dirait quelqu'un qui n'assume pas la responsabilité de ses erreurs, alors le plus adapté me semble être [**irresponsable**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/irresponsable).

[**Orgueilleux**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/orgueil) vient aussi à l'esprit. Quelqu'un qui se croit supérieur aux autres peut facilement leur remettre toujours la faute dessus. C'est une explication, mais ça n'est pas forcément  la bonne ([discussion](http://test.psychologies.com/comment-gerez-vous-vos-conflits-de-couple/resultat/tendance-a-rejeter-la-faute-sur-l-autre)).

Comment: Le mot que je cherche est plus proche d'orgueilleux que d'irresponsable. Ce n'est pas tant le fait de ne pas assumer ses erreurs, mais de reprocher à d'autres ses propres erreurs.

Comment: @radouxju Je trouve qu'irresponsable et orgueilleux sont beaucoup plus proche de ce qu'on cherche que "mauvaise foi" qui signifie plutôt faire preuve volontairement de mauvaise intention. Reprocher les erreurs sur les autres est une conséquence naturelle d'une personne irresponsable et orgueilleuse.

Comment: @Simon Merci pour cette remarque. Mauvaise foi est ce qui ce rapproche le plus du mot que je cherchais, donc je le maintiens comme étant la meilleure réponse (c'est d'ailleurs également celle qui a reçu le plus de vote). Il me semble que la mauvaise foi n'implique pas de mauvaises intentions, mais que la personne qui en fait preuve ne reconnaît pas ses erreurs (même si elles sont manifestes). L'irresponsable ne se soucie pas d'où vient l'erreur (donc ne va pas nécessairement les rejeter sur autrui). L'orgueilleux pourrait avoir ce comportement et c'est un terme unique, mais moins spécifique.

Answer (score 2):

Sans savoir répondre à la question en soi car je ne pense à aucun substantif ou même adjectif précis, je pense qu'on peut aussi parler d'état victimaire.

Mes recherches m'ont également amené à regarder du côté de la victimisation et de l'apitoiement sur soi, mais qui semblent impliquer qu'il y ait une réelle victime, donc sans notion de mauvaise foi.

Excellente question cela dit, car j'ai l'impression d'assister à une recrudescence de ce  comportement, ca serait donc pratique de pouvoir le nommer :-)

Comment: merci, je ne connaissais pas ce mot. Malheureusement, l'adjectif convient mais le substantif a une autre signification: "Dans l'Antiquité, personne qui préparait et frappait les victimes pour un sacrifice. "

Answer (score 2):

Il y a plusieurs réponses possibles pour nuancer les réactions possibles que l'instinct de fuite dû au *déni* peuvent emprunter.

En prenant ce rôle critiquable 'je' pourrait affirmer que lorsque 'on' 'me' demande de 'me' justifier :

> JE suis ***vaniteux, prétentieux***, car je crois ou j'imagine vrai ce qui ne correspond pas à ce qui est perçu par les autres ; plus familièrement ON me dit ***crâneur*** ou ***ramenard***, car je suis satisfait de MOI, quelle que soit la situation si on me met en face de la réalité.
> Ce n'est pas moi qui ait mal agit mais les autres qui n'ont rien compris, ou qui m'ont piégé, persécuté... Ah ! SI la question avait été bien posée, la passe bien faite...
>
> Mais j'insiste et JE deviens *mythomane* et donc ***fabulateur, menteur***, car je fabule, je mens, je simule (surtout à moi-même) pour *ne pas perdre la face*.
>
> ON dit alors que JE suis une personne *peu sûre d'elle, inconsciente, asociale, pas fiable* que JE suis ***'mytho', barjot, pauvre type*** et on m'affuble de tout ce qui permet de dénigrer une personne en qui on ne peut pas avoir confiance... ce qui évidemment n'est pas vrai ! Puisque ce n'est jamais de ma faute !
> ... ce qui pourrait finir en *manipulateur* et ME ferait *contempteur, détracteur* éventuellement *négationniste* voire *pervers*.

Comment: Peut-être que le vote négatif pourrait m'aider à améliorer ma réponse en me disant pourquoi les mots en italique ou en gras ne peuvent pas convenir à définir les différents états qu'une personne qui rejette toute faute sur autrui peut atteindre ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas le mien. JE vous ai plutôt ajouté 1, parce que J'ai beaucoup aimé votre petit tour d'horizon style visite guidée, rempli d'humour et néanmoins plein d'informations. JE serais aux commandes que JE verrais mal comment améliorer un produit aussi bien conçu.

Answer (score 2):

En mode extrême de non reconnaissance de faute ou d'erreur, on pourrait probablement accepter autoagnopathie litéralement refus de la connaissance des "problèmes" sur soi, mais le "pathos" ne se limite pas dans ce cas au refus de reconnaître ses erreurs, mais aussi le refus de reconnaître une maladie etc. Donc on pourait compléter en insérant le mot mentir ? On se rapproche du mythomane, mais c'est tjkrs pas ça!!! Bref il faudrait faire un mot avec les racines les plus approriées, probablement en en piochant de nouvelles dans un dico de grec ancien, en traduisant par exemple : **refus accepter propres erreurs**.  http://www.lexilogos.com/grec_ancien_dictionnaire.htm

Answer (score 0):

Je propose : un propre-juste, la propre justice,

Sans toutefois circonscrire le terme dans un seul mot, cela me fait penser aux postures ds les relations: OK - OK, 
Ok - pas OK, (il/elle se croit tjs OK, et les autres ne le sont pas.)
pas OK - OK, pas OK - pas OK...

Autre expression imagée qui me vient... du jardin d'Eden: "la femme que tu m'a donnée...c’est elle qui (m’a donné du fruit de l’arbre, et j’en ai mangé)

Et enfin ds une chanson d'Abd Al Malik:" c'est pas moi, c'est les autres, les ôôôtres... les ôôôtres...! " (très efficace à citer qd qq1 se justifie pour tout )

Comment: Ce serait plus lisible sans abréviations.

Comment: Vous parlez de "ds qd qq1" ? Si oui, désolée. Je ne connais pas encore les habitudes sur ce site.

Comment: @Waboofun, je propose que vous modifiez votre réponse afin d'enlever les abbréviations. Ce site n'est pas nécessairement visité par des 100% francophones.

Answer (score 0):

C'est un ***M. ou Mme*** ***Je-sais-tout***.  Roger Hargreaves par exemple a écrit une série de bouquins en anglais bien traduite en français pour les enfants.  Ce sont des comptes modernes des leçons qui évoquent des fables qui s'appellent :  *Monsieur/Madame/Mademoiselle [titre de leçon].*. Dans ça cas, il  s'agit du [***narcissisme***](https://https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trouble_de_la_personnalit%C3%A9_narcissique) ou l'égocentrisme. Le narcissisme ne permet que des fautes des autres. On a du mal à comprendre des critiques ; on a toujours raison.

> Selon Marie-France Hirigoyen dans le sens populaire et courant du
> terme, le narcissisme est jugé moralement et péjorativement sous
> l'aspect de la mégalomanie, l'égocentrisme et l'indifférence aux
> autres.

***Madame Je-Sais-Tout*** en fait partie.  Le personnage principal est un  *je-sais-tout.*. Ce n'est jamais de sa faute car elle sait tout.

(D'autres livres dont il y a des dizaines d'autres sujets : *Mme Sage*, *M. Malin*, *Mme Pourquoi*, *Mme Têtue*, *M. Incroyable*, etc.)

[image: page de titre de Mme Je-sais-tout avec un dessin en bleu d'un personnage, une jeune fille peut-être qui lève le doigt]

Answer (score 0):

Voici ce que vous cherchez :

Biais d'autocomplaisance

Answer (score 0):

Bien entendu que la personne décrite dans la question fait de son mieux. Il s’agit d’un ou d’une perfectionniste !

Le monde est fait de ceux qui s’en contentent et de ceux qui tentent de le changer !

Ainsi le perfectionniste conscient de la limite de ses talents, appelle aux autres pour faire mieux qu’il ou elle ne le peuvent.

Bien sûr qu’il râle contre lui-même. Sa propre fragilité lui interdit de reconnaître ses travers en public. Cela nuirait à sa capacité à râler.

Ne méprenez donc pas ses réactions pour de l’orgueil, ce dont il est tout à fait incapable.

De toute évidence, cette personne ne se contente pas de râler face à ses propres limitations. Il râle sur tout !

Râler stimule la productivité, [ainsi le rapporte le très sérieux journal « Le Monde »](https://www.lemonde.fr/economie/article/2013/04/22/dans-les-entreprises-les-raleurs-sont-meilleurs_3164034_3234.html)

Apprendre à râler est indispensable pour celui ou celle qui désire maîtriser la langue française. Qui ne râle pas n’est pas français !

Vous touchez ici à l’essence de l’âme française, celle qui a contribué à l’esthétisme de sa culture, à ses prouesses technologiques. Accomplir quoi que ce soit en France, demande à faire face à une pléthore de critiques que dispense une multitude de râleurs volontaires.

Ainsi éclairé de l’appréciation de vos congénères, vous pouvez œuvrer à réaliser vos projets en tentant de minimiser les critiques des serviables râleurs.

A titre de conclusion, je rappelle les faits suivants :

- [Je râle donc je suis](https://www.ouest-france.fr/sport/raler-un-sport-national-avec-son-championnat-185320)
- 86 % considèrent la France comme « la nation championne des râleurs »
- 93 % des Français s’avouent râleurs
- 57 % des Français estiment qu’il « faut râler dans la vie, sinon on se laisse marcher dessus »
- « près d’un Français sur trois se justifie en disant que cela lui fait du bien et le détend »
- les râleurs gagneraient 20 % de plus que les non râleurs !

[Les râleurs sont les meilleurs](https://www.eyrolles.com/Entreprise/Livre/les-raleurs-sont-les-meilleurs-9782709644853/)